# как выводить (НЕ ИСПРАВИТЬ) ошибки HTTP 500 и HTTP 504 в чат телеграмм бота при возникновении проблем на сайте

Tags: php, yii2, telegram-bot, nginx

есть проект сайта использующий nginx, yii2 и вывод сообщений в телеграм бот,

Вопрос такой, как вывести ошибку HTTP 500 и HTTP 504 (http 403 forbiden выводится) если (как я узнал) php код не будет работать при таких ошибках (500,504) мне сказали что можно разместить скрипт в конфиге nginx, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Вывести откуда и куда? Что и где конкретно приводит к появлению ошибок 500 и 504?

Comment: «http 403 forbiden выводится» — как именно оно выводится сейчас? Что мешает сделать по аналогии для ошибок 500 и 504?

Comment: @andreymal вывести в чат телеграмма, к примеру на сайте есть страница которая может быть перегруженна, и ответ от неё слишком долго ждать (HTTP 504), вследствие чего в чат телеграмма ничего не выводится, ни ошибки ни какого либо сообщения.

Comment: @andreymal ошибка 403 выводится, но то как она выводиться (с помощью PHP) не подходит для ошибок 500, 504, из-за того, что код PHP просто не будет работать (знающий человек подсказал, к сожалению не сказал как это решить)

Comment: ошибку то кто генерирует, сам вэбхук какой-то бота на сайте? Или бот куда то ходит и получает ошибку, которую хочет отобразить?

Comment: @teran бот ходит по сайту и получает ошибку которую нужно отобразить

Comment: Если бот сам отправляет какие-то http-запросы и получает ошибку в ответе, значит не должно быть никаких проблем эту самую ошибку из ответа прочитать. Ошибки 500 и 504 в этом плане абсолютно никак не отличаются от ошибки 403 — все они будут в одном и том же месте в теле ответа. Поэтому теперь становится ещё более непонятно, какая же всё-таки у вас проблема

Comment: @andreymal, немного изменю свой вопрос, задача в том чтобы логировать ошибки сайта в телеграм, проблема 500 и 504 ошибки в том, что обычный конфиг не справится с логированием подобного вида ошибок

Comment: О каком «обычном конфиге» речь? Всё равно ничего не понятно

Comment: @andreymal речь идёт о конфиге nginx, сейчас нашел способ как сделано логирование ошибки 403 в моем прокете ```https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/runtime-logging``` так же нашел похожую тему, где пишут, что ошибка 500 логируется в ```apache``` но в данном проекте используется ```nginx``` ```https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/runtime-logging```